# Events render too far to the right in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am having a strange problem when I render events onto the calendar. About 90% of the time everything is just fine:

[image]

However, the other 10% of the time the events render too far to the right of their respective columns:

[image]

Has anyone had this problem? I don't suspect that it is my code due to it working a majority of the time. I also believe that this problem occurs on every browser.

Below is the basic outline of my code:

```
var myEvent = {
   title: nthClass.prefix.toUpperCase() + ' ' + nthClass.number + ':' + nthClass.section + '\nCRN: ' + nthClass.crn, 
   start: moment().date(objectMonthDay).day(selectedCourseDayOfWeek).hour(Number(hourStart)).minute(Number(minuteStart)).second(0),
   end: moment().date(objectMonthDay).day(selectedCourseDayOfWeek).hour(Number(hourEnd)).minute(Number(minuteEnd)).second(0),
   textColor: '#EAE6DC',
   backgroundColor: backgroundColors[i],
   borderColor: "#7f8c8d"
}
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);
```

Comment: Have you checked the css of those elements with the built-in developper tools of your browser (assuming you're using Firefox or Chrome)?

Comment: **Here is the CSS for the altered event**
`<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-not-end" style="border-color: rgb(127, 140, 141); color: rgb(234, 230, 220); top: 305px; bottom: -407px; z-index: 2; left: 50%; right: 0%; background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34);"><div class="fc-content"><div class="fc-time" data-start="8:00" data-full="8:00 AM - 9:00 AM"><span>8:00 - 9:00</span></div><div class="fc-title">CIS 321:3<br>CRN: 23423</div></div><div class="fc-bg"></div></a>`

Comment: **And the correctly rendered event**
`<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="border-color: rgb(127, 140, 141); color: rgb(234, 230, 220); top: 0.0245278px; bottom: -101.025px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%; background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185);"><div class="fc-content"><div class="fc-time" data-start="5:00" data-full="5:00 AM - 6:00 AM"><span>5:00 - 6:00</span></div><div class="fc-title">HIST 321:3<br>CRN: 23452</div></div><div class="fc-bg"></div></a>'`

It seems that the only difference is the 50% left being applied to the incorrectly one. That's weird..

Comment: Also, setting the left property to 0 does not help this problem. I set `fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-bg and fc-content` all to left: 0 and nothing worked. Even with !important still nothing.. Any suggestions?

Comment: So it's definitely a CSS problem, have you tried to reproduce the issue in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The problem is hard to produce since it only happens about 10% of the time. After trying to set `left:0 !important;` on many different class names nothing works. The event still shows `left:50%;` Does anyone know which class name would be affecting this?

Comment: Also copying the direct CSS path `#calendar > div.fc-view-container > div > table > tbody > tr > td > div > div > div.fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr > td > div > a` did not work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the solution to this problem.

Initially I thought that my added CSS was not working, but after some propagation time it now seems to work just fine. After about 30 attempts to replicate the issue, I did not encounter any problems like I was before.

**Here is the CSS to fix events that render too far to the right:**

`#calendar > div.fc-view-container > div > table > tbody > tr > td > div > div > div.fc-content-skeleton > table > tbody > tr > td > div > a{
left:0 !important;
}`